# format a default values in access 2013 table

Tags: ms-access

I have an access 2013 database that has default values set to alleviate issues with nulls and searches.  I would like the values to be grayed so when the data is viewed in a data sheet format it does not look like actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do that in table, it is possible in a form or report using textbox Conditional Formatting rules. Like:

`Field Value    is equal to    [Forms]![Rates]![tbxRate].[DefaultValue]`